# Can't save High resolution images to sqlite database as blob

Tags: android, sqlite, bitmap, image-scaling

Is it possible to save large images to database? If no, Is there a more efficient way on how I can save an image to my sqlite database? I am able to save and retrieve images stores in my db that are below 1mb but if it goes more than that the app crashes when I try to save them.

here is my code:

```
       @Override
    public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Uri targetUri = data.getData();
            picture_location = targetUri.toString();
            textTargetUri.setText(targetUri.toString());
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));  
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                loginDataBaseAdapter.insertPhoto(byteArray);
                showpic();


            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }   
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void showpic() {

        LoginDataBaseAdapter db = loginDataBaseAdapter.open();
         boolean emptytab = false;
         boolean empty = db.checkPic(null, emptytab);

        //Cursor cursor = loginDataBaseAdapter.fetchProfileImageFromDatabase();  

         if(empty==false)  
         {  
             Cursor cursor = loginDataBaseAdapter.fetchProfileImageFromDatabase();
             cursor.moveToFirst();
                   byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("Path"));  
                    ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);  
                    Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);  
                    targetImage.setImageBitmap(theImage);  
            cursor.close(); 
                }  





        }
```

Comment: `Is it possible to save large images to database`. Yes it is. But it is almost always VERY BAD idea, regardless platform or other issues

Comment: what about saving images as files, then get reference from database to it?

Comment: use only file path reference in database and store image (copy image) to sdcard folder .

Comment: As suggested by other comments - don't save images as BLOBs. Just save a URI to the image location. Very few database systems are efficient with BLOBs and SQLite is no different. What you have to remember is the BLOB concept has been around for very many years and when it was first thought of, "large" was generally way smaller than the amount of data we deal with these days. Very many efficient content management systems and document management systems only deal with URIs within their databases and store the data externally.